# how to send dynamic email template within html table

Tags: php, email, mysqli

why my php variables are not initializing, what is the workaround to send html email with initialized php variable values before sending email?. Im sure I must be missing something.

```
$query=mysqli_query($conDB,"SELECT * FROM client_profile WHERE client_id='1'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $client_name = $row['client_name'];
    }
```

I fetched the client name in `$client_name` from above query.

```
$query2=mysqli_query($conDB,"SELECT * FROM emails WHERE emailfor='1'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {

$from = $row2['fromEmail'];
$sendTO = $row2['to_Email'];
$template = $row2['template'];  //this database column holds this variable $client_name with table template
$subject = $row2['subject'];

}
```

`$template` variable holds the below structure

```
    <div style="color:#333;font-size: 14px;">
    Dear, '. $client_name .'<br /><br /><br />
    <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; border:thin dotted #CCC; padding:5px; color:#333; font-size:13px;">
      <tr>
        <td><h3>Client Information</h3></td>    
      </tr>

      <tr><td>Client Name</td>    <td>'. $client_name .'</td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

now im sending email as below ---

```
$to = $sendTO;
$emailSubject="$subject";
$from = $fromTO;    

$message = '<html><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">';
$message .= '<head>';
$message .= '</head>';

$message .= "$template";    
$message .= "</body></html>";    

$headers = "From: $from \r\n" . "CC: $from";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $from \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

mail($to, $emailSubject, $message,$headers);
```

Im receiving email with the variable name as `Dear, $client_name`
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Write `$message .= "{$template}";`

Or use `str_replace` function =>

```
str_replace($arr , $arr1 , $string)
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with PHP 5.2.x or higher you might want to checkout Mandrill and maybe used with MailChimp for your template generation.

The sandbox mode they have is pretty good.

Mandrill - https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.php.html